# Set SharePoint 2013 Shared document WebPart property (JSLink) in javascript object model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, sharepoint-clientobject

I want to change JSLink property for shared document webpart in javascript.

is there any way to set jslink property ?

ex.

```
documentsList.set_title("My title");
```

i can set the title but is there any way to set jslink ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to set Web Part `JSLink` property via SharePoint JSOM API:

```
var pageUrl = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath;       //current page url
var webPartId = 'ab9149d6-8204-460a-9ecc-4219481ff8ca';   //<-- specify web part id
var jsLinkUrl = '~sitecollection/Style Library/tasks.js'; //<-- specify JSLink url
setupJsLink(pageUrl, webPartId,jsLinkUrl,
  function(){
      console.log('JSLink has been saved');
  },
  function(sender, args) {
      console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

where

```
function setupJsLink(pageUrl, wpId,jsLinkUrl,success,error)
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var page = context.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
    var wpm = page.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    var webpartDef = wpm.get_webParts().getById(new SP.Guid(wpId));
    var webpart = webpartDef.get_webPart();
    var properties = webpart.get_properties();
    properties.set_item("JSLink", jsLinkUrl);
    webpartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
          success();                  
        }, 
        error);
}
```

Comment: its is giving exception like "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Comment: webpartDef.saveWebPartChanges(); is throwing "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it from an app, it won't be possible. The function call will execute correctly, you will receive no errors, but nothing will happen. Just so you know.